# "Извини, не подумал" пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

Подскажите, пожалуйста? Может ли в данном случае стоять тире?

"Извини - не подумал".

Подобно "Не смог попасть в здание - много было народу".

Что-то смущает всё -таки в этом варианте (извини - не подумал).

Answer (score 1):

Можно, если тире должно показать либо молчание/паузу, либо пропуск (хоть и пропущено как будто много текста).